# Get SoilGrid data per x,y coordinates

Tags: python, api, soilgrids

In the past I was able to get SoilGrid data per x,y coordinates (lat,lon) using Python with the below URL:

```
url = f'https://rest.soilgrids.org/soilgrids/v2.0/properties/query?lon={lon}&lat={lat}'
```

I haven't used this API in a long time and now I see it has changed. According to [here](https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/03-WCS-2.0.ipynb) they added a new argument `subsets` which takes in a list of tuples, one tuple per axis, and the result is a raster/matrix according to the subset. I would like to get data the old way, providing lat,lon, and get data as JSON.

Is it still possible to get data per lat,lon via Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's changed is the host. Use `rest.isric.org` instead of `rest.soilgrids.org`.

`wget "https://rest.isric.org/soilgrids/v2.0/properties/query?lon=34.5&lat=1.299"` returns a big chunk of JSON data which is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks, now it seems to work. Can I trust that nothing else has changed? for example the parameter names?

Comment: I can't find a formal spec or documentation about that API, so you'll probably have to ask the Soilgrids team themselves. I only inferred this from using their web map and looking at the request it made when selecting a point!

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that in the SoilGrid FAQ (https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#What_if_I_did_not_find), under "What if I did not find an answer to my question?" they say to post questions here in StackExchange and write the tag 'soilgrids' which I did..